# How to open in a WebBrowser an Angular project in WinForm Framework 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

I have to integrate an old VB.NET project written in Framework 3.5 a new Angular project that should communicate with the VB application, i've tryed to use WebBrowser but as it uses IE 9 that wasn't the solution as angular at that level is just not supported.

So i've tryed to search some libraries which i could use to run chrome as WebBrowser, but after looking some of the answers in stackoverflow i've found libraries that all uses Framework 4.5>

I've yet tryed to use CEFSharp but as i said it requires Framework 4.5>..

So which could be the solution to integrate an Angular project to be opened inside a WinForm written in Framework 3.5?

Comment: Do you need the angular app to look like it is part of the winforms app, or is it okay to launch a browser, like a separate form?

Comment: @tgolisch the app need to look like it's native, so like it's part of the winform

Comment: Ok. There is a way to embed a browser window as a winform control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the WebBrowser control.  It gives you a lot of options for controlling it, adding content, url, etc.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview